# Issues with in Talend 6.5 after postgres upgrade from 9.6 to 11.5

Tags: postgresql, talend

I am using Talend DI 6.5.
I am getting below error while processing data from big csv file (10 mill rows) after migrating Postgres database from version 9.6 to 11.5

```
An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
Exception in component tPostgresqlOutput_1 (emp_table)
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
```

ETL job is working fine on 9.6 postgres version.
Do I need to change any settings in Talend DI for this DB upgrade?
any driver upgrade is requier? Please suggest